# How to update variables defined in controller as syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following is the code I am trying:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var appCtrl = app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl(){
  var appCtrl = this;
  appCtrl.variable = "search";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl as ctrl1">
     {{ctrl1.variable}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl as ctrl2">
    <input type="search" ng-model = "ctrl2.variable"/>
     {{ctrl2.variable}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When I update `ctrl2.variable`, but `ctrl1.variable` is not updated.

How can I update that without using `$scope`?

Comment: May help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170464/i-have-two-divs-with-the-same-ng-controller-in-angularjs-how-can-i-make-them-sh

Comment: That is all the point of `controllerAs` syntax - to prevent scope shadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution that I can find without using **`$scope.$watch`** is with a shared state, like below.

Basically both controllers have the same reference to the object and any change to the value is observed.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('SharedState', SharedState);

function SharedState(){
  var shared = this;
  state = {variable: "search"};
  
  shared.getState = function() {
    return state;  
  }
  
  return shared;
}

app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl(SharedState){
  var appCtrl = this;
  appCtrl.sharedState = SharedState.getState();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl as ctrl1">
     {{ctrl1.sharedState.variable}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl as ctrl2">
    <input type="search" ng-model = "ctrl2.sharedState.variable"/>
     {{ctrl2.sharedState.variable}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah! Actually I just did it with `Service`. But this answer also works. Will post mine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adricadar's answer is perfectly fine.

But I just wanted to post the one that I wrote:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var appCtrl = app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

appCtrl.$inject = ['ShareDataService'];

function AppCtrl(ShareDataService){
  var appCtrl = this;
  appCtrl.variable = "search";
 
   appCtrl.setSearchQuery = function () {    
       ShareDataService.setSearchQuery(appCtrl.variable);
    }
     
 appCtrl.getSearchQuery = function () {    
        return ShareDataService.getSearchQuery();
    } 
 
}

var sharedDataService = app.service('ShareDataService',ShareData);

function ShareData(){
  var shareDataService = this;
    
  shareDataService.searchQuery = "";
  
  shareDataService.getSearchQuery = function(){
 return shareDataService.searchQuery;
  }
  
  shareDataService.setSearchQuery = function(searchQuery){
 shareDataService.searchQuery = searchQuery;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl as ctrl1">
     {{ctrl1.getSearchQuery()}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl as ctrl2">
    <input type="search" ng-model = "ctrl2.variable" ng-change="ctrl2.setSearchQuery()"/>
     {{ctrl2.variable}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The logic is:

1. Service is a **Singleton Object**. Only one instance is created.
2. Added a setter and a getter method.